# Is it possible to init a variable in the while condition body for Kotlin?

Tags: while-loop, kotlin, variable-initialization

In the code below:

```
    var verticesCount: Int // to read a vertices count for graph

    // Reading until we get a valid vertices count.
    while (!Assertions.checkEnoughVertices(
            verticesCount = consoleReader.readInt(null, Localization.getLocStr("type_int_vertices_count"))))
        // The case when we don't have enough vertices.
        println(String.format(Localization.getLocStr("no_enough_vertices_in_graph"),
                              Assertions.CONFIG_MIN_VERTICES_COUNT))

    val resultGraph = Graph(verticesCount)
```

we are getting next error on the last line:

```
Error:(31, 33) Kotlin: Variable 'verticesCount' must be initialized
```

**Assertions.checkEnoughVertices** accepts a safe type variable as an argument (verticesCount: Int), so it's impossible for verticesCount to be uninitialized or null here (and we're getting no corresponding errors on those lines).

What's going on on the last line when already initialized variable becomes uninitialized again?

Comment: Does `Assertions.checkEnoughVertices` have a parameter named `verticesCount`?

Comment: @marstran yes, it is the only parameter of this method

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The syntax you've used denotes a function call with [*named arguments*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#named-arguments), not the assignment of a local variable. So `verticesCount =` is just an explanation to the reader that the value which is being passed here to `checkEnoughVertices` corresponds to the parameter of that function named `verticesCount`. It has nothing to do with the local variable named `verticesCount` declared just above, so the compiler thinks you've still to initialize that variable.

In Kotlin, the assignment to a variable (`a = b`) is *not* an expression, so it cannot be used as a value in other expressions. You have to split the assignment and the while-loop condition to achieve what you want. I'd do this with an infinite loop + a condition inside:

```
var verticesCount: Int

while (true) {
    verticesCount = consoleReader.readInt(...)
    if (Assertions.checkEnoughVertices(verticesCount)) break

    ...
}

val resultGraph = Graph(verticesCount)
```

Comment: It's a quite complete and straightforward answer with a proposed solution. The described case is clear for me now.

Comment: How about a "do while" instead of an infinite loop that you then need to break out of?

Answer (score 6):

Well, technically it is possible to assign values to variables in the while condition - and anything else you might want to do there, too.
The magic comes from the `also` function:

Try this: (excuse the completely useless thing this is doing...)

```
var i = 10
var doubleI: Int
while ((i * 2).also { doubleI = it } > 0) {
    i--
    println(doubleI)
}
```

Any expression can be "extended" with "something to do" by calling `also` which takes the expression it is called upon as the `it` parameter and executes the given block. The value `also` returns is identical to its caller value.

Here's a very good article to explain this and much more: https://medium.com/@elye.project/mastering-kotlin-standard-functions-run-with-let-also-and-apply-9cd334b0ef84

Comment: Thank you @zordid, really useful!